# Returned web service data not populating tableview

Tags: objective-c

Hey,  I cant seem why this code is not working? I am trying to add my returned data from a web service into the uitableview, however failing miserably. The table shows up blank everytime. It seems it doesnt like the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. But honestly I am not sure. I cant spot it for nothing. Please help. Thanks!

```
#import "RSSTableViewController.h"


@implementation RSSTableViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
 if (self = [super initWithStyle:style]) {
    songs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
return self;
}



- (void)loadSongs
{

 [songs removeAllObjects];
[[self tableView] reloadData];

// Construct the web service URL
NSURL *url =[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/get_params"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                         cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                     timeoutInterval:30];

if (connectionInProgress) {
    [connectionInProgress cancel];
    [connectionInProgress release];
}

[xmlData release];
xmlData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

connectionInProgress = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                       delegate:self];
}
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self loadSongs];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[xmlData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
[connection release];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:xmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

songs = [responseString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

newSongs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0; i < [songs count]; i++) {
    [newSongs addObject:[songs:i]]);
}
     [songs autorelease];


[[self tableView] reloadData];
// 
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [connectionInProgress release];
    connectionInProgress = nil;

    [xmlData release];
    xmlData = nil;

    NSString *errorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Fetch failed: %@",
                         [error localizedDescription]];
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:errorString
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [actionSheet showInView:[[self view] window]];
    [actionSheet autorelease];

    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [newSongs count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
                 initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                 reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"] autorelease];
    }

    [[cell textLabel] setText:[newSongs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];



    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: Why don't you put some logging after the webservice so you can see what is returned?  This is too much code for a single question - you need to narrow down your problem.

Comment: I did. The data is populating the array as expected. This takes place in the connectionDidFinishLoading method. After that, uitableview methods does not want to add the data to the tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you're ignoring warning messages, which is a no-no in Objective-C. The following code can't possibly work:

```
[newSongs addObject:[songs:i]]
```

What you probably meant to write was something like this:

```
[newSongs addObject:[songs objectAtIndex:i]]
```

But instead of doing all this:

```
newSongs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0; i < [songs count]; i++) {
    [newSongs addObject:[songs:i]]);
}
```

why not just do this?

```
newSongs = [songs mutableCopy];
```